# Can't find the right regexp

Tags: regex, qt, qstring, qregexp

I'm working with QString (Qt 4.8) and I want to extract this kind of string `src="http://media.cineblog.it/9/91f/Big-Bad-Wolves-primo-trailer-per-il-crime-thriller-israeliano.jpg"`
 from QString using QRegExp. But I can't find the righ regular expression to do it. The string isn't in a img tag.

Comment: what did you try ? please post your code, sample source data and expected output

Comment: I've tried this pattern src\\s*=\\s*\"(.+)?\'

Comment: @user2508526, don't change the title to mark the question as answered. Instead mark the answer that helped you as accepted, see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

try using the pattern

```
(src="[^"]+")
```

Comment: @user2508526: The way it works here is to accept the answer by clicking the check mark top left of the answer, not adding solved to the title :-)

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler answer:

```
src=".*"
```

.* Means "match as much of anything (in this line) that you can".

Comment: I am not sure this works as well if there are multiple src="..." on a line